# Creating a Player object in a physics engine

Tags: c#, box2d, physics, farseer-physics-engine

I have a working physics environment using Farseer - but how do I create a player object that can walk around?

My current attempt involves applying forces to a rectangular body whenever keys are pressed.

This... works... to some degree. The player box moves around and such, after significant angle damping doesn't flip over much either. But I want a smooth moving simple player that can walk around and climb slopes but not walls and stuff like that. As it currently stands, the player object can climb any slope no matter how steep due to continue sideways force being applied. The player also does not stop quickly, but rather slides heavily due to low friction - and raising the player body's friction value doesn't help all that much.

I just don't know how to do a standard player object without making it move around in ridiculous ways due to the physics engine being a full physics engine.

Answer (score 0):

I've already got a pretty reasonable answer to this [over here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/70676/288), with some video examples.

The short version is: You cannot reasonably use rigid body physics to simulate biped locomotion in the kind of responsive way you'd want for a platformer. You have to do something else.